# Mute (not pending) a caller during a call

Tags: calls, mute

I want to use conference mode for calls in a webradio. But i need to control who can speak, i can't find a way to mute a participant who should be cut to let others speak.

So, there is no way to mute someone during a call ?

I know pending but it's not that i want (caller can't hear the radio with pending).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look for a third party app like this one:

[Voxeet Conferencing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.itic.voxeet.android)

(the one not based on regular phone call are the more versatile)

Comment: It's seems like to Skype, it's not using GSM ? I can't using that for my webradio concept.

Comment: no, it is not based on regular phone call. This is why you get more option / feature.
To say the truth, I don't know if what you ask is technically possible. (I don't know if the phone receive the diferentes voices separately)